# javascript convert array to object for send data by ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, object

I would like to send a list of data by ajax. So I push all data in a 2d array

But the ajax of jquery not accept the array data, the data must be object or query string

since the Object of javascript is no push function, I must use array to build the list of data.
Is there any function in jquery or javascript, let me

```
var countLine=$("line").length;
var lines=$("line");
var lineArr=new Array();
var linesArr=new Array();
var x1, y1, x2, y2;
for(i=0; i<countLine; i++)
{
    lineArr['x1']=lines[i].getAttributeNS(null, "x1");
    lineArr['y1']=lines[i].getAttributeNS(null, "y1");
    lineArr['x2']=lines[i].getAttributeNS(null, "x2");
    lineArr['y2']=lines[i].getAttributeNS(null, "y2");
    linesArr.push(lineArr);
}
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    data: linesArr,

    async: true,
    cache: false,

    success: function(data){
        $("#txt").text(data);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert("fail");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
data: linesArr
```

to

```
data: { linesArr: linesArr }
```

This will send an object with a single property, `"linesArr"`, which contains the value of your array.

---

EDIT: you have a bigger problem. You are trying to store non-numeric properties in an array, as shown in this line:

```
lineArr['x1']=lines[i].getAttributeNS(null, "x1");
```

You are also reusing the same `lineArr` "array" each time through the loop. The following code would work much better:

```
var lines = $("line");
var linesArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; ++i) {
    var line = lines[i];

    linesArray.push({
        x1: line.getAttributeNS(null, "x1"),
        y1: line.getAttributeNS(null, "y1"),
        x2: line.getAttributeNS(null, "x2"),
        y2: line.getAttributeNS(null, "y2")
    });
}
```

Then you would access your data like `$_POST["linesArr"][0]["x1"]`.

Comment: I am not sure the data is sent correctly, I have tried different way to get the value, but I cannot get the value


 echo $_POST[0]['x1'];
 echo $_POST['x1'][0];
 echo $_POST["linesArr"]['x1'];
 echo $_POST["linesArr"]['x1'][0];
 echo $_POST["linesArr"][0]['x1'];
 echo $_POST[0]["linesArr"]['x1'];

Comment: thank you very much, now is success, and I have found that why I cannot access the data before, because the two word of "data: { linesArr: linesArr }" can not be same, so now the linesArr: linesArray is ok.



But one thing I still not understand, why it is a big problem for storing non-numeric properties in an array and reusing  the same lineArr "array"?

Comment: You can reuse the same name; that is not a problem. I changed my sample code to `linesArray` for clarity because I hate abbreviations, but you can feel free to change it back and things won't break.

Comment: As for why you shouldn't store non-numeric properties in an array... in JavaScript, as in most other languages, arrays are typical computer-science arrays, i.e. collections indexed by nonnegative numbers. PHP has a thing called an "array" that is really a map from any string to any object, which is confusing; in JavaScript such a map is called an object. So trying to put nonnumeric properties on a JavaScript array (or C# array, or Java array, or C++ array, or Pascal array...) just doesn't make sense, and will give nonsensical results and/or errors.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the object to a JSON string using `JSON.stringify()`.

http://json.org/

Comment: JSON.stringify(linesArr) to be exact, but this answer is good.

Comment: The JSON.stringify() is also accept Object, so I need convert the array to object first.

Comment: `stringify()` will accept arrays, objects and scalars. No conversion is necessary.

Comment: Please try these code, in the first alert box, it will display [], while in the second box, it will display {"x":3,"y":4}, so I said it is only accept object.

'code'( var arr=new Array();
 var obj=new Object();
 arr['x']=1;
 arr['y']=2;
 obj.x=3;
 obj.y=4;
 alert(JSON.stringify(arr));
 alert(JSON.stringify(obj));)